# No viable conversion from 'mapped_type'

Tags: c++, xml, c++11, xml-parsing

This is my code to compare XML files, using a map to define xml tag names to content.

```
#include "pugi/pugixml.hpp"

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    pugi::xml_document doca, docb;
    std::map<std::string, pugi::xml_node> mapa, mapb;
    std::map<int, std::string> tagMap {make_pair(1, "data"), make_pair(2, "entry"), make_pair(3, "id"), make_pair(4, "content")};

    if (!doca.load_file("a.xml") || !docb.load_file("b.xml")) {
        std::cout << "Can't find input files";
        return 1;
    }

    for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
        auto id = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
        mapa[id] = node;
    }

    for (auto& node: docb.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
        auto idcs = node.child_value(tagMap[3]);
        if (!mapa.erase(idcs)) {
            mapb[idcs] = node;
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
src/main.cpp:20:30: error: no viable conversion from 'mapped_type' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>') to
      'const char_t *' (aka 'const char *')
        for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
                                    ^~~~~~~~~
```

On recommendation I tried this approach:

```
        auto id = node.child_value(tagMap[3].c_str());
```

But I still get same error. It seems me trying to use a map to define the tag names has caused a lot of issues over just hardcoding it, but mapping it seems logical since in the future I will move the map to an external file so I can run the program for different XML tags without recompiling each time.

Comment: Please see the line where it shows the error.... and where you're actually changing your code.

Comment: Just a guess: `const auto&`

Comment: @DieterLücking ```const auto id = node.child_value(tagMap[3].c_str());``` Like this? I get the same error

Comment: @Nawaz I see the line with the error but I don't understand it.

Comment: @JamesWillson +& (in your original code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the error closely

```
src/main.cpp:20:30: error: no viable conversion from 'mapped_type' (aka 'std::__1::basic_string<char>') to
  'const char_t *' (aka 'const char *')
    for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1]).children(tagMap[2])) {
                                ^~~~~~~~~
```

You'll see that you're passing a `std::string` to something that expects a `const char*`. Specifically:

```
doca.child(tagMap[1])
```

`tagMap[1]` is a `std::string` and `child()` expects a `const char*`. So:

```
for (auto& node: doca.child(tagMap[1].c_str()).children(tagMap[2].c_str())) {
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried this code, but it gives me this error: ```src/main.cpp:21:9: error: non-const lvalue reference to type 'const char *' cannot bind to a temporary of type
      'const char_t *' (aka 'const char *')
                auto& id = node.child_value(tagMap[3].c_str());
                      ^    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
``` Does tis mean it should be for ```(const &auto...```

Comment: @JamesWillson The error states that you're binding a non-const reference to a temporary. What does that suggest to you that the fix is?

Comment: I'll try a few things and get back to you

Comment: Putting const here ```for (const auto& node....``` and here ```auto id = node...``` worked! Thank you